# Select unique value from column A along with unique value from column B

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R:

```
user    hobby      user_profile_url
1       reading    "https://...user1"
1       dancing    "https://...user1"
2       dancing    "https://...user2"
2       gaming     "https://...user2"
3       gaming     "https://...user3"
4       cooking    "https://...user4"
4       singing    "https://...user4"
...
```

I'm trying to choose a unique user for each unique hobby (as long as it possible).

Desired output:

```
user    hobby      user_profile_url
1       reading    "https://...user1"
2       dancing    "https://...user2"
3       gaming     "https://...user3"
4       cooking    "https://...user4"
4       singing    "https://...user4"
...
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I think I have something that works.

```
uniqueUserPerHobby <- function(df){
  vec1Arr <- c()
  vec2Arr <- c()
  used_id <- c()
  for (a_label in unique(df$hobby)){
    if (nrow(df[df$hobby==a_label,])==1) {
      used_id <- c(used_id, df[df$hobby==a_label,]$user )
      vec1Arr <- c(vec1Arr, df[df$hobby==a_label,]$user)
      vec2Arr <- c(vec2Arr, a_label)
    } else {
      i<-1
      df_multy <- df[df$hobby==a_label,]
      for (a_user in df_multy$user) {
        i<-i+1
        if (nrow(df[df$user==a_user,])==1) {
          used_id <- c(used_id, a_user)
          vec1Arr <- c(vec1Arr, a_user)
          vec2Arr <- c(vec2Arr, a_label)
          break
        } else if (i == length(df$user)) {
          if (! a_user %in% used_id){
            used_id <- c(used_id, a_user)
          }
          vec1Arr <- c(vec1Arr, a_user)
          vec2Arr <- c(vec2Arr, a_label)
        } else if (! a_user %in% used_id) {
          used_id <- c(used_id, a_user)
          vec1Arr <- c(vec1Arr, a_user)
          vec2Arr <- c(vec2Arr, a_label)
          break
        }
      }
      if (!a_label %in% vec2Arr){
        if (!df[df$hobby==a_label,]$user[1] %in% used_id){
          used_id <- c(used_id, df[df$hobby==a_label,]$user[1])
        }
        vec1Arr <- c(vec1Arr, df[df$hobby==a_label,]$user[1])
        vec2Arr <- c(vec2Arr, a_label)
      }
    }
  }
  new.df <- dplyr::left_join(data.frame(user=vec1Arr, hobby=vec2Arr, stringsAsFactors = F), df, by=c("user", "hobby"))
  return(new.df)
}
```

This is probably not the best way to do this, but I tried it on two different data.frames and it worked.

```
> dat <- data.frame(user  = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), hobby = c("reading","dancing","dancing","gaming","gaming","cooking","singing"), user_profile_url = c("https://...user1","https://...user1","https://...user2","https://...user2","https://...user3","https://...user4","https://...user4"), stringsAsFactors = F)

> uniqueUserPerHobby(dat)

  user   hobby user_profile_url
1    1 reading https://...user1
2    2 dancing https://...user2
3    3  gaming https://...user3
4    4 cooking https://...user4
5    4 singing https://...user4
```

Comment: Why does User1 get only 1 hobby while User4 gets two in your output? Are you saying IF there is no other user for that hobby, repeat the same user?

Comment: Try `df1[!duplicated(df1[1:2]),]`

Comment: @akrun it seems his desired output is just a little more complicated. He wants only a single user per hobby - in a way that maximizes the number of users...

Comment: For example, `uniq.dat <- dat[!duplicated(dat[1:2]),]; uniq.dat[!duplicated(uniq.dat$hobby),]` will skip out on User3 (why I posted my comment @ChiPak)

Comment: @EvanFriedland: I agree that it's more complicated. `user3` gets `gaming` because `user1` got reading, which leaves `user2` with `dancing`. Pretty complicated...I deleted my original comment because I see that you understood what OP wanted as output already...

Comment: Your edit works in your case but is specific to the dataset format-- meaning you function can only work on your specific df case. You couldn't easily, for example. fund unique hobbyperUser, or any other column combination. The size of your function is also pretty big. If you would like a function that works for any 2 column case, with no library dependencies, please see my edit :)

Comment: @EvanFriedland Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wooooweee not easy. I did it using base R and made a function as well. Give it a try:

**Your data:**

```
dat <- data.frame(user  = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), hobby = c("reading","dancing","dancing","gaming","gaming","cooking","singing"), user_profile_url = c("https://...user1","https://...user1","https://...user2","https://...user2","https://...user3","https://...user4","https://...user4"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**My function:**

```
somewhatUnique <- function(df, colA, colB){
  uniq.df <- df[!duplicated(df[,c(colA, colB)]),]
  tb.uniq.df <- table(uniq.df[,c(colA, colB)])
  new.tb <- row(tb.uniq.df)
  new.tb[] <- rownames(tb.uniq.df)[new.tb]
  new.tb[tb.uniq.df == 0] <- NA
  j <- apply(new.tb, 2, as.list) # supply table columns as individual lists
  # expand.grid can take list arguments so we can handle dynamic unique hobbies
  combos <- expand.grid(lapply(j, function(x) do.call(rbind,x)), 
                        stringsAsFactors = F) # all possible options
  k <- combos[complete.cases(combos),] # options without NA
  s <- rep(NA,nrow(k)) # initialize vector
  for(i in 1:nrow(k)) s[i] <- length(unique(k[i,,drop = T]))
  L <- as.list(c(k[which.max(s),]))
  names(L) <- unique(df[,colB]) 
  # find position in split and return correct row
  by_B <- split(df, df[,colB])
  takerows <- as.list(c(mapply(function(x,y) match(x,y[,colA]), 
                               x = L, y = by_B)))
  out <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(z,r) z[r,], z = by_B, r = takerows)))
  out <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(out, unlist)) # formatting output correctly
  out <- out[order(out[,colA]),] # sorting by user
  rownames(out) <- NULL
  out
}
```

**Example use:**

```
somewhatUnique(dat, "user", "hobby") # all unique hobbies, maximizing unique users
#  user   hobby user_profile_url
#1    1 reading https://...user1
#2    2 dancing https://...user2
#3    3  gaming https://...user3
#4    4 cooking https://...user4
#5    4 singing https://...user4

somewhatUnique(dat, "hobby", "user") # all unique users, maximizing unique hobbies
#  user   hobby user_profile_url
#1    4 cooking https://...user4
#2    2 dancing https://...user2
#3    3  gaming https://...user3
#4    1 reading https://...user1
```

Let me know if you have any issues/questions!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but got this error:
`Error in lapply(j, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)) : object 'j' not found`

Comment: Big edit, should work for different cases, see my examples

Comment: This is grate! It works for any 2 column case. Classic. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried to make it as general as possible, **BUT** I've only tested it on your data, and it'll throw you some warnings but that don't affect the output (based on the current data). *I can't guarantee it'll work all the time*, but it should get you started.

Starting with your data, which I save as a tibble:

```
df <- tibble(user=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), hobby=c("reading","dancing","dancing","gaming","gaming","cooking","singing"),user_profile=c("user1","user1","user2","user2","user3","user4","user4"))
```

**Data Preprocess**
I save only unique `user` and `user_profile` in a separate data frame. This will be used at the end:

```
up <- df %>% 
        group_by(user) %>% 
        summarise(user_profile=unique(user_profile))

   user user_profile
  <dbl>        <chr>
1     1        user1
2     2        user2
3     3        user3
4     4        user4
```

I re-format your original data frame so that `hobby` are columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
new <- df %>% 
         mutate(dummy=1) %>%
         complete(user,hobby) %>%
         group_by(user) %>%
         spread(.,hobby,dummy) %>%
         filter(!is.na(user_profile))

   user user_profile cooking dancing gaming reading singing
  <dbl>        <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1        user1      NA       1     NA       1      NA
2     2        user2      NA       1      1      NA      NA
3     3        user3      NA      NA      1      NA      NA
4     4        user4       1      NA     NA      NA       1
```

**Big Function**
I then wrote a recursive function that takes the input data frame and the expected output data frame as arguments. I tried to annotate each step:

```
complicated <- function(x,y) {
    # Find unique user:hobby pairs
    col.sum <- x %>% 
                 select(-user_profile) %>% 
                 colSums(.,na.rm=T)
    unique.col <- names(col.sum)[col.sum==1]

    # Format unique user:hobby pairs
    # Save as 2-column data frame: user, key
    unique.hobby <- x %>% 
                     select_(.dots = unique.col) %>% 
                     gather(key,value,unique.col) %>%
                     filter(value==1) %>%
                     select(-value)

    # Filter out (ie remove) unique user:hobby pairs
    restof.hobby <- x %>%
                     filter(!(user %in% unique(unique.hobby$user)))

    # Row-bind output data into single data frame
    y <- rbind(ungroup(y),ungroup(unique.hobby))

    # If all unique user:hobby pairs have not been found
    # Perform above operations again but with only subset of original data frame
    if (nrow(restof.hobby) > 0) {
         complicated( restof.hobby, y )
    } else {
         return(y)
    } 
}
```

**Data Process**
I initialize the final output data frame:

```
final <- tibble(user=NA,key=NA)
```

The function call:

```
complicated(new,final) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(user)) %>% 
    arrange(user) %>%
    full_join(.,up,by="user")
```

**Output**

```
   user     key user_profile
  <dbl>   <chr>        <chr>
1     1 reading        user1
2     2 dancing        user2
3     3  gaming        user3
4     4 cooking        user4
5     4 singing        user4
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error `Error in tibble(user=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), hobby=c("reading", : no column names detected in 'frame_data()' call`

Comment: You might need to load `library(tibble)` at the beginning.